# How can i get data at the angular controller using factory from web api without using port number?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

This is my module,

```
var app= angular.module('myApp', []);
```

I have this code at the angular end,

```
app.factory("CustomerRegistrationInformation", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
    var resource = $resource("http://localhost:8996/api/customerregistration");
    return resource;
}]);
```

But I want a process which is look like below,

```
app.factory("CustomerRegistrationInformation", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
    var resource = $resource("~/api/customerregistration");
    return resource; 
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All requests made from a browser support relative links, so simply starting with a root relative path will work just fine.

```
$resource("/api/customerregistration");
```

Using this as a relative path will ensure that all requests are relative to the root of the website being served up.

In your case it means `http://localhost:8996` when running locally, but could easily be `http://www.my-awesome-domain.com` when deployed to production.